# Uploading a tuning file to my car

Tags: ford, diesel, electronic-control-module, turbocharger, ecu-mapping

I would like to remap my car myself. I will be buying a tuned map from mychiptuningfiles.com for my Ford Focus 1.6 TDCI so I only need to download my stock map and upload the tuned stock map. What cable and software do I need to be able to do this with my laptop? I found a few devices but they are expensive.

Comment: If you could rent a Bosch VCM II then you'll be fine.

Answer (score 2):

Ask the vendor (mychiptuningfiles.com) what they recommend. The different programmers available - trifecta, HP Tuners, etc. - all use different file formats, so which one you can use will depend on what format the tune vendor uses.

You MAY be able to rent a programmer. Some tune vendors will do that for you. Or, better yet, have it dyno tuned at your local speed shop, which can cost approximately the same as buying a tune and a programmer.

Good luck.

Comment: I think I have seen some who offer 2 dyno runs and the remapping all as one package - may be worth checking out - the risk of "blowing" your ecu may not be worth the agro...